# ssh with StrictHostKeyChecking

Tags: networking, command-line, server, ssh, sshpass

When I am connecting the other machine with ssh, every time I answered this question with yes/no -

```
user@computer$ ssh user@host
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses
  ~/.ssh/known_hosts:xx: [hashed name]
  ~/.ssh/known_hosts:xx: [hashed name]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

then, I gave the `yes` for all the time, then only I can able to access the other machine

I get to know that there is a parameter in `ssh` to remove this question while connecting through `ssh` which is `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` and it worked, I just simply enters the password without answering the above question.

I go through few answers, but i dont get the full clarity

Does using ssh with `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` is same as giving `yes` in the above question?

I dont know about the other machines[about trust], but I definitely need to access using `ssh` and answer the above question as `yes` and enters the password and I do my job.

Is there any other way to remove this question while connecting `ssh`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `accept-new`, SSH will add new keys to your hosts file. It would be the same like setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no` and always connecting to a new host. In both cases SSH will automatically add the key. However if a host is known and it changes its keys (created new keys, man in the middle, etc.) than the setting `accept-new` will *not* permit a connection to this host, while the setting `no` will allow it.

When you set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `yes` you'll have to manually update your known hosts file. The second example above will fail and in the first example SSH will *not* make a connection to that host.